# How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and observableCollection in MVVM pattern?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have an ObservableCollection of Products in the Model, and I want the ViewModel to listen to any changes in the ObservableCollection of Products.

Im not sure about how to go and implement it. Ive read several tutorials, but most of them are not MVVM specific.

Should i implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in the ViewModel class, how do I specify that i want to listen to the OberserableCollection of Products?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this has already been answered, but there is more to consider.

1) a ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged, that's one of the things that makes it a ViewModel.  Even in the unlikely case that the only property it exposes is the ObservableCollection, it will need to raise property changed when the actual ObservableColelction property is changed (more on this in item 3)

2) do you really want the ViewModel to listen for these changes or the View?  Those are two different things.  The ViewModel should hold an ObservableCollection which is then bound to the View.  What you want is for the View to react to those changes.  In that case, Brandon is correct that ObservableCollection does this for you out of the box.  So the View has an instance of the ViewModel set as a DataContext and some visual element in your View is bound to the ObservableCollection (like an ItemsSource on a ListBox).

3) the exception is the ObservableCollection property itself in the ViewModel.  While ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged, that is part of the collection object: when that object reference changes (like it is recreated) in the ViewModel, then the ViewModel still needs to report that the Property for the ObservableCollection has changed.

Just some thoughts.

Comment: Thanks very much, they are very useful comments. 
1. I do want the ViewModel to listen to the changes in the OberservableCollections in Model. The View has dataContext set to my ViewModel, and the textbox is binded to the observableCollection in ViewModel, so once the observableCollection  in ViewModel and View are binded, the View should automatically reflect the change.

2. Thanks for pointing that out, I will have to implement the iNotifyProperty, too :) But Im not worrying about it at this stage, I just want to get things going, and make modifications along the way.

Comment: 3. I am not entirely sure on the implementation of the actions, and I didnt find many detailed tutorials on it, would you have any ideas? Thanks again :)

Comment: The confusing parts of your response are this: 1) the ObservableCollection should belong to your ViewModel, not the Model itself.  I would find it strange that a Model class uses ObservableCollection. 2) Why do you have a TextBox bound to a collection?  3) Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your ViewModel should be the first thing you do, so you are already "at that stage".  Most folks put that in a ViewModelBase class so they always have it.

Comment: I don't have anything at the moment, but I'm in the process. I give a presentation called "Practical MVVM" that includes a simple implementation.  You can download the PPT at "http://practicalmvvm.com/Artifacts/Practical MVVM.pptx" and the Solution at "http://practicalmvvm.com/Artifacts/sample_no_source_control.zip".  They would make more sense to you if you could see the presentation, but hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Joel. thanks for your response.
1. If I use do not use an ObservableCollection for in my Model, then will I be able to notify the ViewModel if there are some changes in the Model?
2. Sorry, I meant my textbox is binded to the property of my ObservableCollection in the ViewModel class. 
3. emm.. I already have the PropertyChanged implemented in my BaseViewModel class, Im just not sure how to use it... and the problem is I cant find any sample code online :(

Comment: You don't have to use ObservableCollection for notification: traditional events could do that just fine. Your question implies that your Model is actively rebuilding itself rather than waiting for the ViewModel to request it to rebuild: is that correct?

Comment: @Rosie - you say you already have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented in your base class: does it include a method for raising the PropertyChanged event?  If so, add code to call that method at the appropriate time: it will look something like RaisePropertyChanged("PropertyName") where "PropertyName" represents the name of the property you want to reevaluate.  This is typically in the Setter for the property but can be called from anywhere inside the ViewModel as needed.  (When you call it is all about timing.)

Answer (score 3):

[ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, so you don't need to.

Comment: OK, so do I have to tell my ViewModel explicitly to listen to the change in Model?

Comment: No, you just need to bind to the ObservableCollection. When items are added, removed, or the collectin is refreshed, your UI will be notified. Here's a good article that explains it. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLListVsOCollections.aspx

Comment: Also, make sure that you don't replace the ObservableCollection with another instance. If you have a reason to empty the whole collection and replace it with something else, you need to Clear() the collection and then Add() or AddRange() the new items to it. If you replace the instance, the view will lose its bindings.

Comment: @nlawalker: the Binding itself is still in effect, but the object it was pointing to is no longer available. Putting it that way implies the Binding has to be coded again which it does not. Instead, the binding has to be re-evaluated, which is why you raise PropertyChanged on the collection Property.  Always using Clear and Add works fine but is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @BrandonZeider - I agree that was a little unconventional, and certainly not what I intended. I just wanted to add information to the thread for anyone who might find it later.