# How to implement Actions for observableCollections in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Im using MVVM.

I am implementing my data as OberservableCollections in Model, and I want the ViewModel to listen to and update any changes in the OberservableCollections of data in Model.

I know you have to implement some Actions, e.g. inset, add, etc in ViewModel. But I can not find any tutorial on it, can someone please provide some ideas, thanks :)

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant, but...how is this different from your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570697/how-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-and-observablecollection-in-mvvm-pattern

Comment: Do you want your ViewModel to notify your Model that changes to the collection have occurred?

Comment: opps, I thought I asked a different question yesterday, apparently not :P emm.. No, I want my ViewModel to get notified, when there are changes in the Model.

Comment: My Model consists of Product, and Products. Products is an ObservableCollection of Product. But Im still unsure how to pass this on to the ViewModel, and how is my ViewModel going to get notified about the changes in Model. Unfortunately, I cant find many documents regarding this. (Though there are quite a lot of material on INotifyPropertyChanged..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to the MVVM pattern, read [this post by Jeremy Likness](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html), a Silverlight MVP. He gives basic examples of ViewModels, views, models, binding, commanding, etc.

As far as passing the model objects to the ViewModel, that all depends on where the model objects are coming from. For example, in most LOB applications, you will get data from the server via WCF, which introduces a layer of complexity to the pattern and the implementation.

If instead you mean "how does my ViewModel get notified when the user changes some data on the view", then that notification comes from your ViewModel implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, and your View binding to the properties exposed by your ViewModel. I think reading Jeremy's blog post will clear a lot of this up for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Yes, I do get the data from the server via WCF, which I have implemented, and it works fine. The only problem is that it is a asynchronous service call, and it comes back "too late", (after the page has been loaded), that is why I need to tell the ViewModel to listen to any changes in Model, and update itself accordingly, since the View feeds off the ViewModel. :)   I have now implemented my data list in Model as a OberservableCollection, and now I am implementating a eventHandler in the ViewModel to listen to it.. :)  Im a new grad, ... hence number of questions...:P

Comment: You don't need it to be an ObservableCollection on the server side, but that certainly won't hurt. When your WCF service call returns, simply set YourObservableCollection = ObservableCollectionFromServiceCall;

Comment: You can take the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation from the blog post, put it into a base class, call it ViewModelBase or something similar, and make all of your ViewModels derive from that class. That should be all you need to get binding working.

Comment: Thanks. But I thought the ObservableCollection already has INotifiefPropertyChanged implemented? In the ViewModel, if I just handle the events generated by the ObservableCollection in Model. E.g.  NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add: then just update my observableCollection in ViewModel, which in turn updates the View. Would that work? Then do I still need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: ObservableCollection does. Your ViewModel needs INotifyPropertyChanged though. Read that blog post to understand why. You don't need to listen for changes, add, etc. Just set the ObservableCollection that comes back from your WCF service to the ObservableCollection in your ViewModel that your View is binding to.

Comment: thanks, I will :) but the WCF service comes back to the Model, hence the "binding" of the ObservableCollection in Model and the one in ViewModel :) I thought it is better that way, since we then keep all the data in the Model, and all the business logic in the ViewModel ?

Comment: Well that certainly complicates the design. Since you're new to the pattern, I recommend that you get it working in it's most simple form and then experiment from there to find what fits for you. Most of the time people invoke the WCF service from the ViewModel, and the "model" is completely server side (you get a copy of the model objects, also called DataContracts, when you Add Service Reference). But like I said, it's gets more complicated from there.

Comment: If at some point you want to start abstracting your WCF calls, check out my blog post. It won't make sense to do something like this for a small application though. For a small app, just invoke the services from your ViewModel. http://brandonzeider.me/2010/microsoft-net/wcf-service-call-encapsulation-and-abstraction/